# JSX - How do I get the object values of something a few layers deep?

Tags: reactjs, object, jsx

I'm trying to display the native name of a selected country from a countries API.

To get to it via console log it looks like

```
console.log(country.name.nativeName.???.common)
```

country is a prop passed down of the selected country (ex. Andorra) and ??? is the language of the selected country (ex. cat). So for every selected country ??? is going to be different.

In regular javascript I can get the native name via:

```
Object.values(
                data[i].name.nativeName
            )[0].common;
```

But in JSX I can't get

```
console.log(Object.values(country.name.nativeName));
```

Or any variation of to work, it's just gives me an error of can't read properties of nativeName.

```
console.log(Object.values(country));
```

Will return

```
0: 
common:"Andorra"
nativeName:cat:{official: "Principat d'Andorra", common: 'Andorra'}
```

How can I access nativeName.common?

Edit to include the whole country object:

```
{
    "name": {
        "common": "Andorra",
        "official": "Principality of Andorra",
        "nativeName": {
            "cat": {
                "official": "Principat d'Andorra",
                "common": "Andorra"
            }
        }
    },
    "tld": [
        ".ad"
    ],
    "cca2": "AD",
    "ccn3": "020",
    "cca3": "AND",
    "cioc": "AND",
    "independent": true,
    "status": "officially-assigned",
    "unMember": true,
    "currencies": {
        "EUR": {
            "name": "Euro",
            "symbol": "€"
        }
    },
    "idd": {
        "root": "+3",
        "suffixes": [
            "76"
        ]
    },
    "capital": [
        "Andorra la Vella"
    ],
    "altSpellings": [
        "AD",
        "Principality of Andorra",
        "Principat d'Andorra"
    ],
    "region": "Europe",
    "subregion": "Southern Europe",
    "languages": {
        "cat": "Catalan"
    },
    "translations": {
        "ara": {
            "official": "إمارة أندورا",
            "common": "أندورا"
        },
        "bre": {
            "official": "Priñselezh Andorra",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "ces": {
            "official": "Andorrské knížectví",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "cym": {
            "official": "Tywysogaeth Andorra",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "deu": {
            "official": "Fürstentum Andorra",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "est": {
            "official": "Andorra Vürstiriik",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "fin": {
            "official": "Andorran ruhtinaskunta",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "fra": {
            "official": "Principauté d'Andorre",
            "common": "Andorre"
        },
        "hrv": {
            "official": "Kneževina Andora",
            "common": "Andora"
        },
        "hun": {
            "official": "Andorra",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "ita": {
            "official": "Principato di Andorra",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "jpn": {
            "official": "アンドラ公国",
            "common": "アンドラ"
        },
        "kor": {
            "official": "안도라 공국",
            "common": "안도라"
        },
        "nld": {
            "official": "Prinsdom Andorra",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "per": {
            "official": "شاهزاده‌نشین آندورا",
            "common": "آندورا"
        },
        "pol": {
            "official": "Księstwo Andory",
            "common": "Andora"
        },
        "por": {
            "official": "Principado de Andorra",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "rus": {
            "official": "Княжество Андорра",
            "common": "Андорра"
        },
        "slk": {
            "official": "Andorrské kniežatstvo",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "spa": {
            "official": "Principado de Andorra",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "srp": {
            "official": "Кнежевина Андора",
            "common": "Андора"
        },
        "swe": {
            "official": "Furstendömet Andorra",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "tur": {
            "official": "Andorra Prensliği",
            "common": "Andorra"
        },
        "urd": {
            "official": "اماراتِ انڈورا",
            "common": "انڈورا"
        },
        "zho": {
            "official": "安道尔公国",
            "common": "安道尔"
        }
    },
    "latlng": [
        42.5,
        1.5
    ],
    "landlocked": true,
    "borders": [
        "FRA",
        "ESP"
    ],
    "area": 468,
    "demonyms": {
        "eng": {
            "f": "Andorran",
            "m": "Andorran"
        },
        "fra": {
            "f": "Andorrane",
            "m": "Andorran"
        }
    },
    "flag": "",
    "maps": {
        "googleMaps": "https://goo.gl/maps/JqAnacWE2qEznKgw7",
        "openStreetMaps": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/9407"
    },
    "population": 77265,
    "fifa": "AND",
    "car": {
        "signs": [
            "AND"
        ],
        "side": "right"
    },
    "timezones": [
        "UTC+01:00"
    ],
    "continents": [
        "Europe"
    ],
    "flags": {
        "png": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/ad.png",
        "svg": "https://flagcdn.com/ad.svg",
        "alt": "The flag of Andorra features three equal vertical bands of blue, yellow and red, with the coat of arms of Andorra centered in the yellow band."
    },
    "coatOfArms": {
        "png": "https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/ad.png",
        "svg": "https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/ad.svg"
    },
    "startOfWeek": "monday",
    "capitalInfo": {
        "latlng": [
            42.5,
            1.52
        ]
    },
    "postalCode": {
        "format": "AD###",
        "regex": "^(?:AD)*(\\d{3})$"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share a json representation of the object? That would make things easier.

Comment: Edited the post to include the country object, also the link to the data api https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all

Comment: This isn't do to with jsx/react - if `console.log(Object.values(country));` gives you  `[{common:"Andorra", nativeName: {cat:{official: "Principat d'Andorra", common: 'Andorra'}}}]` then you just need to access `Object.values(country.nativeName)[0].common`. You seem to be confusing what you have in the `country` variable as being your entire `country` object you posted when really it just holds the `name` object based on what you've said `console.log(Object.values(country));` shows.